# Auto generate income and expense Pie Chart in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, pie-chart

Am just crating an app by using daily expenses for that i need to include pie-chart graphical view.i searched many tutorials but probably all are having same story.actually my need is auto generation of pie-chart which includes user's income and expenses.can anyone suggest good tutorials?

Comment: Check out this library: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart, you should be able to find any information on how to use it inside

Comment: *can anyone suggest good tutorials?* [check section: Don't ask about...](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Try EazeGraph :) i tried myself and it's really easy to setup.

link: [EazeGraph Github](https://github.com/blackfizz/EazeGraph) (Tuturial and how to setup in the README.md)